# Understanding backbone.js attributes and toJSON()

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm confused and could use some help.

I'm inside a render function and I have the following three debug lines:

```
            console.debug(this.model);
            foo = this.model.toJSON();
            console.debug(foo);
```

The output for the first line is a model instance with the data fetched from the server and the attributes property is populated with what I would expect.

However, the second console.debug call contains an empty object.

What gives? Shouldn't this second bit of debug output contain the same attributes but JSONified?

Below is the complete bit of code:

```
    function get_race() {

    var RaceModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: api_root + 'race/1/?format=json',

    });

    var RaceView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: _.template('<h1>a template</h1><h2>desc: <%= year %></h2>'),
        initialize: function() {
            this.model = new RaceModel();
            this.model.fetch();
            this.render();
        },
        render: function() {
            console.debug(this.model);
            foo = this.model.toJSON();
            console.debug(foo);
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model));
            return this;
        }
    });


    var race_view = new RaceView({ el: $("#backbone_test") });
```

Comment: what browser are you using?  I used to do stuff like this in Firefox/Firebug and see the model in question

Comment: toJSON in this usage should return the object representing the attributes property on the model instance - it won't be exactly the same as the model, because the model has other properties and methods on it, so without seeing the attributes, I couldn't say what you should see specifically

Comment: one thing to add - don't pass this.model to your template function, pass this.model.attributes

Comment: These were all very helpful responses, thank you! The key was realizing what was happening with the reference to the logged object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely being tricked by the result in the log. The reason the object is logged with the correct values is because console.log() keeps a reference to the object that was logged. This can be observed in Chrome using the following html page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var object = { title: null };
    console.log(object);
    function update() { object.title = document.getElementById("title").value; }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="title" type="text" value="New title"/><br/>
    <button onclick="update()">Update title</button>
</body>
</html>
```

1. Load up the page in Chrome without the developer tools loaded.
2. Open the javascript console and check that the value of the logged instance is null.
3. Close the javascript console.
4. Click the button to update the title.
5. Reopen the javascript console. The title is now updated with the new value, even if it is the same log line.

To ensure that the values have been loaded before you render the view you need to wait for the result. Personally I would go for nEEbz solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think what's happening is that render is being called before the model is fetched.  You should put this in initialize before you call fetch and remove the call to render.

```
this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
```

When render is called straightaway like that, this.model.toJSON() will return an empty object because there's nothing in there at that point.  But your debugger is going to update this.model when it's fetched because it's displaying a reference.

To prove the point, try logging something immutable like console.log(JSON.stringify(this.model));

Comment: Kinda ironic that you named it race model when you've got a race condition here ;)

Answer (score 0):

change your fetch code to:

```
that = this
this.model.fetch(
    success: function () { 
        that.render();
);
```